# Permutation test replications aggregation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, permutation-test

Short version:
Is it right, and if yes, what is the right way to combine permutation tests applied on n randomly selected subsets of a bigger dataset? I was not able to find a publication that tackles this subject.

Long version:
I am performing a permutation-based 2-way ANOVA on a dataset with large dimensionality, a sample corresponding to each individual and  consisting of landmarks, that are grouped by sides (it is a stereometry symmetry analysis) and replications. I am trying to assess the effect of each landmark, conditioned on individuals, on sides and on their interaction. I have observed, through 1000, or even 10k, iterations experiments, that by increasing the individuals number above 50, I get a p value less than 0.05 for every landmark effect I am assessing. I want to find regions that are more significant than others, therefore increasing the sample size reduces the resolution. To try and avoid the effects of cherry-picking, I am applying the experiment 5 different times, randomly selecting subsets of 50 individuals each time. Then, I get the p-value by averaging the results from the experiments. Is that a good way to avoid specialization for my approach? Also, if you could please provide me with a citation, or some key search terms to research literature, it would be extremely helpful for supporting my case.

Comment: Does it come down to:  when I increase my sample size, everything becomes significant, so I can't tell what is "most" significant any more?

Comment: Yep!...........